# How to add values to a list in mvc 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, for-loop

I have model definition as:

```
public class CMBCategory
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<CMBCategory> children = new List<CMBCategory>();
}
```

I need to add values to this list , but there may be n number of subitems like

```
a)Redbook
    a.1) Wedding
          a.1.1) Christian
              .
              .
    a.2)Baptism
b)Florenta
```

Using the following code I just get only first level of sub products:

```
foreach (var items in lstcatlist)
{
    CMBCategory cmb = new CMBCategory();
    cmb.ID = items.FirstOrDefault().catid;
    cmb.Name = items.FirstOrDefault().title;
    foreach (var item1 in items)
    {
        if (item1.parent == 0)
        {
            cmb.children.Add(new CMBCategory() { ID = item1.prod_id, Name = item1.desc });
        }
    }
    lstmain.Add(cmb);
}
```

Here lstcatlist has the values:
[image]
It may be because of my loop structure , please provide a way to find the correct structure   to loop n number of sub products if any

```
var lstcatlist = (from s in context.M_ProductCategory
                  join p in context.M_CategoryDetails on s.ID equals p.CategoryID
                  select new
                  {
                      catid = s.ID,
                      title = s.Title,
                      prod_id = p.ID,
                      parent = p.ParentID,
                      desc = p.Description
                  }).GroupBy(x => x.catid).ToList();
```

Comment: What is the data in `lstcatlist` and what are its models?

Comment: @Stephen Muecke   List<CMBCategory> lstmain = new List<CMBCategory>();

Comment: No - again - what is in `lstcatlist` and what are its models?

Comment: @Stephen Muecke ohh sorry!!!

Comment: Updated the values at question

Comment: OK. You also need to edit the question to show how your query to generate `lstcatlist` (its not clear why you need the grouping and how you want to use it - your code makes no sense so you need to explain what you trying to do :). I can then add an answer.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke Ok

Comment: @Stephen Muecke , I added it in the quetion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122358/discussion-between-neethu-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use recursion

```
void main()
{
    PrintTree(listOfCategorys);
}

void PrintTree(IEnumerable<CMBCategory> list)
{

  foreach(var item in list)
  {
     PrintTree(item.children);
     DoSomehtingWithTheObject(item); // ie. print it , or what ever you want 

  }
}
```